# Subspace don't heritate the source_files and resources property in cocoa pods: why?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to exclude files depending on subspecs. Roughlt, my (local) podspec looks like

```
s.source_files = "all"
s.resources = "some"

s.subspec 'CoreData' do |sp|
   sp.exclude_files = ...
end
s.subspec 'Realm' do |sp|
   sp.exclude_files = ...
end
```

When in my Podfile I call `pod 'MyPod/Realm'`, no file is imported.

I am missing something?

Should I add `sp.source_files = "all"` to my subspecs and if yes why? 
It seems that subspecs don't heritate the `source_files` property nor the `resources` property.

Answer (score 0):

So far, my solution is to do

```
  #s.source_files = "all"
  #s.resources = "some"

  s.subspec 'CoreData' do |sp|
    sp.source_files = "all"
    sp.resources = "some"
    sp.exclude_files = ...
  end

  s.subspec 'Realm' do |sp|
    sp.source_files = "all"
    sp.resources = "some"
    sp.exclude_files = ...
  end
```